# load nth number of class from url in iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to load specific div of external url in iframe, For that i am doing this,

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $('#iframediv').load('URL_TO_LOAD .tborder');
});

<div id='iframediv'></div>
```

Its working great, but issue is i have 7 div with this class `.tborder` in iframe. I want to load only 5th `.tborder` in iframe.

Suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `:nth-of-type()` selector like this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $('#iframediv').load('URL_TO_LOAD .tborder:nth-of-type(5)');
});
```